# Balloon-airlock filling up fast

Tags: mead, beginner

So I’m making some very simple mead (it’s my first time) and I use a balloon on top of my “container” to make sure it doesn’t blow up. But the balloon has already been blown up quite significantly in only about five hours. Is this normal? It seem a bit much?

Too much yeast?

Sorry for not knowing much about this.

Update: Thanks A lot for the help :-)

Comment: You can thank us by rating our answers with an up vote.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

It’s normal, but if you have a very good balloon on there, it might not pass air quickly enough.  You can loosen it a touch to let some air out from time to time, but I highly recommend you spend $4 on a bung and airlock combo from Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

That's very normal and shows that your yeast is active.  It's possible that you over-pitched more yeast than was necessary but it shouldn't hurt anything.  Now be patient and let it ferment for about a month before tasting.  Should be great by then.

Cheers.